# Rails Advanced Query Possibly With Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I am trying to do an advanced query that allows a search by category (see ERB below).

The search term will be a string. Essentially there are three cases:

1. **The search term is the direct name of a crop** (CropCategory) and the query should return all donations that have a category name matching the search term.
2. **The search term is a category (not a specific crop)** and the query should return all donations with the category name matching the search term AND all donations with the category name matching any of the names of crops within the category specified by the search term.
3. **The search term doesn't match a crop or a category** it returns nothing.
   [image: ERB of the Database]

Currently I can handle case 1 without any problems if the search term is 'corn' for instance all entries of category 'corn' are returned.

Case 2 is only partially handled. If the search term is 'leafy greens' all entries of category 'leafy greens are returned' however, entries of category 'lettuce' or 'kale' are not despite the CategoryCrop belonging to lettuce also belonging to the category 'leafy greens'

The query code looks like:

```
donations = Donation.all.order("date DESC")
donations = donations.joins(:category).includes(:category)
donations = donations.where("name like ?", "%#{search_term}%").references(:categories) if search_term.present?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is join all donations to both their category and to crops associated with that category, then filter on either category name or crop name matching the given string. Let's start with doing that in SQL:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM donations d
JOIN categories ca       ON ca.id = d.category_id
JOIN categories_crops cc ON cc.category_id = ca.id
JOIN crops cr            ON cr.id = cc.crop_id
WHERE
  ca.name LIKE 'foo%'
OR
  cr.name LIKE 'foo%'
```

So suppose your data set looks like the following:

```
    donations           categories           crops        categories_crops 
----------------   ------------------   ------------   ---------------------
id | category_id   id | name            id | name      crop_id | category_id
================   ==================   ============   =====================
1  | 1             1  | leafy greens    1 | lettuce    1       | 1
2  | 1             2  | dark greens     2 | broccoli   2       | 2
3  | 2                                  3 | kale       3       | 1
                                                       3       | 2
```

The JOINs above will produce a pre-filtered set that looks something like this, slimmed down for easier representation:

```
donations X categories X categories_crops X crops
-------------------------------------------------
donation_id | category.name | crops.name
=================================================
1           | leafy greens  | lettuce
1           | leafy greens  | kale
2           | leafy greens  | lettuce
2           | leafy greens  | kale
3           | dark greens   | broccoli
3           | dark greens   | kale
```

As you can see, each donation ID appears next to all the crops that were under the category it donated to (note that, at this point, I'm not sure if I've got your data model right or wrong. Either way, the principles I'm describing should help you and others). So, if we filter by **leafy**, we'd get back donations 1 and 2. If we filter by **kale**, we'd get back donations 1, 2, and 3.

Hopefully that all makes sense, and we can get to the final step -- translating the SQL to ActiveRecord. It's pretty direct:

```
Donations
  .joins(category: :crops)
  .where('categories.name LIKE :term OR crops.name LIKE :term', term: "%#{search_term}%")
```

The `join` may need to be `category: { categories_crops: :crops })`, or something else, depending on exactly how your relations are set up. The idea is to traverse the relations you've defined to build the join like described above.

---

**EDIT:** Per OP's clarification in comments, the data model also contains an implicit hierarchy of categories, inferred from the crop -> category relationship but substituting the crop name for the category of the same name. Implicit relationships, where additional logic is needed but not made obvious from the database design, can be tough to query -- often a sign that the data model might need updating. But let's start by updating the query.

We need to also include categories which "belong to" the category being searched on, so we'll need an additional join. Since not every category has a parent category, it should be an outer join. The join criteria, however, will be weird. My first thought is to create a temporary table that joins categories to their parent category names, and just left join onto that. So the query becomes:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM donations d
JOIN categories ca       ON ca.id = d.category_id
JOIN categories_crops cc ON cc.category_id = ca.id
JOIN crops cr            ON cr.id = cc.crop_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ca2.name as parent_category_name, ca3.id as child_category_id
  FROM categories_crops cc2
  JOIN categories ca2 ON ca2.id = cc2.category_id
  JOIN crops cr2 ON cr2.id = cc2.crop_id
  JOIN categories ca3 ON ca3.name = cr2.name
) cp
ON cp.child_category_id = ca.id

WHERE
  ca.name LIKE 'foo%'
OR
  cr.name LIKE 'foo%'
OR
  cp.parent_category_name LIKE 'foo%'
```

Translating to Rails:

```
Donations
  .joins(category: :crops)
  .joins(<<-SQL)
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT ca2.name as parent_category_name, ca3.category_id as child_category_id
      FROM categories_crops cc2
      JOIN categories ca2 ON ca2.id = cc2.category_id
      JOIN crops cr2 ON cr2.id = cc2.crop_id
      JOIN categories ca3 ON ca3.name = cr2.name
    ) cp ON cp.child_category_id = categories.id
  SQL
  .where('categories.name LIKE :term OR crops.name LIKE :term OR cp.parent_category_name LIKE :term', term: "%#{search_term}%")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This seems to help if the search term is **kale** i get both entries for **kale** and **leafy greens** but if the term is **leafy greens** i still only get **leafy green** entries.

Comment: @Bevilacqua can you elaborate more on what you expect to get in that scenario? I'm not sure why a search for `leafy greens` should return more than `lettuce` and `kale`.

Comment: That is actually exactly what I want it to return but currently it only returns entries marked explicitly with leafy greens. Ex. If three entries are in donations with categories: [lettuce], [kale], [leefy greens]. I will only get the leafy green entry.

Comment: Aren't kale and lettuce both crops which belong to categories, rather than categories themselves? I think I'm missing something about your data model. Is the sample data in my answer assuming something incorrect?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I made it clear. When a crop is created a category is also created with the same name. A donation has a category. A category has one or more crops. The reason being that the client may not know the exact contents of a donation. It may be marked as just Leafy Greens and be a mix of lettuce and kale for example.

Comment: So if a donation is made of lettuce, it's assigned the category 'lettuce', and you want a search for 'leafy greens' to pull it up as well. But how is your system to know that the lettuce category should be tied to the leafy greens? Just the fact that a crop called lettuce somewhere in your database is under that category?

Comment: That's what the categories_crop table is for. If I make a category for leafy greens I can then create a categories crop that belongs to lettuce and leafy greens.

Comment: @Bevilacqua take a look at my edit to the answer. If I'm still off, you'll need to post your database schema and some sample data before I can help more.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am getting the following error. `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column ca3.category_crop_id does not exist
LINE 2: ...         SELECT ca2.name as parent_category_name, ca3.catego`. Embarrassed to say I don't completely follow the SQL code so sorry in advance if I just did something stupid!

Comment: Change that reference to just `ca3.id`; I accidentally prefixed the primary key with the table name, which isn't Rails default behavior (but preferred by many DBAs).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146463/discussion-between-bevilacqua-and-robert-nubel).